# How to build MinGW linux compiler from sources?

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, mingw, wine

I want to install `wine` using a remote terminal. My main limitation is that I can't use `sudo`, or `apt-get`. To install wine, I am following the steps described [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine). When I run the command `/configure --enable-win64`, I get:

```
(...)
configure: MinGW compiler not found, cross-compiling PE files won't be supported.
configure: libXxf86vm 64-bit development files not found, XFree86 Vidmode won't be supported.
configure: libOSMesa 64-bit development files not found (or too old), OpenGL rendering in bitmaps won't be supported.
configure: OpenCL 64-bit development files not found, OpenCL won't be supported.
configure: pcap 64-bit development files not found, wpcap won't be supported.
configure: libdbus 64-bit development files not found, no dynamic device support.
configure: libsane 64-bit development files not found, scanners won't be supported.
configure: libusb-1.0 64-bit development files not found (or too old), USB devices won't be supported.
configure: libgphoto2 64-bit development files not found, digital cameras won't be supported.
configure: libgphoto2_port 64-bit development files not found, digital cameras won't be auto-detected.
configure: gstreamer-1.0 base plugins 64-bit development files not found, GStreamer won't be supported.
configure: OSS sound system found but too old (OSSv4 needed), OSS won't be supported.
configure: libudev 64-bit development files not found, plug and play won't be supported.
configure: libSDL2 64-bit development files not found, SDL2 won't be supported.
configure: libcapi20 64-bit development files not found, ISDN won't be supported.
configure: libcups 64-bit development files not found, CUPS won't be supported.
configure: libopenal 64-bit development files not found (or too old), OpenAL won't be supported.
configure: libnetapi not found, Samba NetAPI won't be supported.

configure: Finished.  Do 'make' to compile Wine.
```

I understand that I need a MinGW compiler first. Every search I do on how to install it leads to using `sudo` or `apt-get`, which I can't do.
So my question is, how to install `gcc-mingw` from sources or without using `sudo`, `apt-get`??
Thank you.

Comment: 1 - Grab the sources, and compile them into a directory under your control. 2 - If any fail due to dependencies, then jump to 1. 3 - point `configure` to the directory of the specified installation. 4 - give up as it's too much hard work, there could be hundreds of packages you need to grab, configure and install all individually.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have much experience. Can you please provide an answer with the steps well described? as well as the commands I need to run on my remote terminal?

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that it is just not worth it. I am talking about potentially 100's of source code packages that you will have to download, configure and install, and have to fiddle about with config options, and ensure that none of them conflict with any runtime binaries already installed, and this will probably take many months given you do not have the experience. Either get root privs, install a vm or find some other hardware which you will have full permissions on.

Comment: Did you mention that just installing gcc-mingw from sources on linux would take me months?

Comment: Yes, I did. There are about 17 additional sources you may need to install depending on what outcome you are looking for, I assume Wine. Each of them could have 17 additional source code requirements, and each of them could have 17 additional source code requirements as well. 17 * 17 = 289, 17 * 17 * 17 = 4913. Do you really want to look at configuring ~200 or ~5000 additional packages, and that's just for mingw? You also realise, that running Wine over that remote link, may not work?

Comment: No no, I actually have a remote terminal, which belongs to a docker container running in the cloud, so I want to install wine in that container. My purpose is never to use wine locally from the remote terminal. Specifically, what I have is an account at https://www.pythonanywhere.com/